# How to Traverse the blocks of transactions in hyperlegder fabric?

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric

Is there any **chaincode API** that gives an iterator over the blocks of transactions in hyperledger fabric?
I want to get a list of all transactions in the ledger.

Comment: Did you find this out?

Comment: NO! @antoniovassell

Answer (score 1):

You can use the QSCC (query system chaincode) and query 1 by 1 starting from block 0 until H where H is the ledger Height - whom you can obtain using the QSCC call GetChainInfo.

https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/core/scc/qscc/query.go

Answer (score 0):

If using the Node SDK, you would first call [queryInfo](https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/release-1.4/Channel.html#queryInfo) to get the block [height](https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/release-1.4/global.html#BlockchainInfo) and you can then call [queryBlock](https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/release-1.4/Channel.html#queryBlock) to iterate over the blocks. Parsing the blocks is another issue and I don't know of any easy method to do that [ref](https://lists.hyperledger.org/g/fabric/topic/how_to_read_the_blocks_of/30861359?p=,,,20,0,0,0::recentpostdate%2Fsticky,,,20,2,0,30861359).

Example response from queryInfo: [1](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/siddjain/cc1a9b35adfecb013104540756c3265f/raw/09861cb3e0665b7cba0ad6cea5e13a56568a765d/gistfile1.txt)

Example response from queryBlock: [2](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/siddjain/5675e484d7be9cc635666a4b91e94161/raw/633bc43e088d77d93e2f690198ca2d0f8b3a0a8c/gistfile1.txt)

above use 1.2 of Fabric